# Add admin sdk to an existing initialized app

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-admin

Is there a way to add admin sdk to an app that's initialized by client firebase already? When I tried to initialize both, it throws an error saying that I can't initialize default app twice. I need client side firebase for login etc, but admin for managing users, both in the same app/website.
What I did so far:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);

var admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp({
'credentrial': ...
 }); //error
var serviceAccount = require("./api_key.json");
var admin_auth = admin.auth();


export { auth, db, admin_auth };
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear from the code you've shared, but the Admin SDK and Firebase SDK should **normally** never be used together and the Admin SDK should never be used outside a server or local test environment.

Comment: The Admin SDK also has a modular interface to match the client SDK. Import it using `import { /* ... */ } from 'firebase-admin/app'`.